# Nginx Rewrite Not rewriting the url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have tried this for hours and can't seem to get it. I copied other examples and still can't get rewrite to work.
I need my url on nginx to look like http://myurl.com/main/login, http://myurl.com/somethigelse/home, est. Any Help Appreciated. I'm new to nginx, seems a lot faster.

My nginx rewrite looks like this:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?db=$1&action=$2 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /index.php?db=$1&action=$2 last;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. Do you tell nginx to reload the configuration (do a `sudo service nginx reload`)? Otherwise, nginx will still be using the old config.

Note, that you can use one line by making the final slash optional using a question mark:

```
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?db=$1&action=$2 last;
#                         ^
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. Yes I restart and reload the service

Comment: @TVarcor so what does that mean exactly, "it doesn't work"? What URL are you requesting, and what is the result? Perhaps also post the rest of the config, the problem may be somewhere else.